# SwiftUIでstructのプロパティを変更できない

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUIを使って”tap”と書かれた`Button`をタップすると、`Text`に「good morning」と表示させるものを作ろうとしたのですが、うまくいきません。

おそらく、`greeting`のプロパティ`morning`（Bool型）の変更がうまくいってないものと思われます。これはstructが参照型であることによる現象だと思うのですが、解決策が思いつきませんでした。

[image: view]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var greetingText = greeting()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            greetingText
            Button(action:{
                self.greetingText.changeText()
            }){
                Text("tap")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct greeting:View {
    @State private var morning:Bool = false
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            if morning {
                Text("Good morning")
            }else{
                Text("hello")
            }
        }
    }
    func changeText(){
        self.morning = true
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button`を`Greeting`に持たせるか、`@Binding`で`ContentView`と`Greeting`の間で変数を紐づけることで解決できると思います。

(1) `Greeting`側で`Button`アクションの処理

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Greeting()
        }
    }
}

struct Greeting: View {
    @State private var morning: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if morning {
                Text("Good morning")
            } else {
                Text("hello")
            }
            Button("tap") {
                self.morning.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(2) `@Binding`を使ってふたつの`View`の間で変数を紐付け

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var morning: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Greeting(morning: $morning) // <-
            Button(action: {
                self.morning.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("tap")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct Greeting: View {
    @Binding var morning: Bool // <- @Binding

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if morning {
                Text("Good morning")
            } else {
                Text("hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```